# Find value of the limit: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2}$

Tags: limits

Determine value of the limit:

$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2}$$

My try:

$$1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Hence: $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}=?$$

But, come here, i do not know how, because please help me.

Comment: Up to things that don't matter, it's $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n^3}.$$

Comment: I think: $\sqrt[n]{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}=(n/6)^{\frac{1}{n}}(1+n)^{\frac{1}{n}}(1+2n)^{\frac{1}{2n}\: 2}\to 1.1.1=1$

Answer (score 7):

$$1\leftarrow\sqrt[n]{n}<\sqrt[n]{1^2+\cdots+n^2}<\sqrt[n]{n^3}\to 1$$

The limit used above can be shown via AM-GM for instance:

$$1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{2}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\Big(1+\cdots+ 1+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}\Big)\geq \sqrt[n]{n}\geq 1$$

Comment: Simplify things by noting that $\sqrt[n]{1^2+\cdots+n^2}\geqslant\sqrt[n]{1}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $n^3 < n(n+1)(2n+1) < n*2n*3n = 6n^3$, you have
$$n^{3 \over n} < (n(n+1)(2n+1))^{1 \over n} < 6^{1 \over n} n^{3 \over n}$$
Since $6^{1 \over n}$ goes to $1$, in order to show your limit is $1$ it suffices to show that 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{3 \over n} = 1$$
You can do this via L'hopital 's rule for example.