# A proof in $\varepsilon$-language for $\lim \sqrt[n]{1^2+2^2+...+n^2} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I found a proof that $\lim \sqrt[n]{1^2+2^2+...+n^2}=1$ by $\varepsilon$-language, but I think it's quite complicated and not sure that it's correct.

My question is:
1- Is my proof correct?

2- Is there another simpler proof in the sense of $\varepsilon$-language?

Please help me. Thanks.

*Solution:*

Let $a_n=\sqrt[n]{1^2+2^2+...+n^2}-1$. Then $a_n>0$ and:

$$ (a_n+1)^n= 1^2+2^2+...+n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

By the binomial theorem we have:

$ (a_n+1)^n = 1 + na_n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}a_n^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}a_n^3+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}a_n^4+\cdots+a_n^n $

Since $a_n>0$, then $(a_n+1)^n>\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}a_n^4$ and therefore:
$$\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}>\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}a_n^4$$

This is equivalent to

$$(n+1)(2n+1)>\dfrac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4}a_n^4 \Leftrightarrow a_n^4<\dfrac{4(n+1)(2n+1)}{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}$$

$$\Rightarrow a_n^4< \dfrac{8(n+1)^2}{(n-2)^2(n-3)}=\dfrac{8}{n-3}\Big(1+\dfrac{3}{n-2}\Big)^2<\dfrac{128}{n-3}.$$

Thus: $a_n<\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{128}{n-3}}$. For every $\varepsilon >0$, take $N>3+\dfrac{128}{\varepsilon^4}$, then for all $n\ge N$,
$$ n-3 \ge N -3 > \dfrac{128}{\varepsilon^4} $$

Thus: $ \varepsilon^4 > \dfrac{128}{n-3} \Rightarrow \varepsilon > \sqrt[4]{\dfrac{128}{n-3}} >a_n $.

Hence, $\lim a_n=0$ or equivalently, $\lim \sqrt[n]{1^2+2^2+...+n^2} =1$.

Comment: This seems good. Neat trick.

Comment: Questions on the same limit [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611801/find-value-of-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn1222-cdotsn2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find value of the limit: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611801/find-value-of-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn1222-cdotsn2)

Comment: @KingLogic Note that the OP asked for verification of their proof.

Comment: Moderator asked me to delete my question, however, what I'm asking here is that: 
1- Was my proof correct?
2- Whether it's correct or not, it's not a nice one (in the sense of $\varepsilon$-language). Is there another simpler proof in $\varepsilon$ language? 
So, it's quite different from the linked one, then I wouldn't delete my question.

Comment: 1. Your proof is correct and 2. it is a very nice proof. I suggest you to post your solution to the linked question. The other answer uses $\lim \sqrt[n] n = 1$ and squeeze theorem, which is good, but the proof of that limit use an argument very similar to what you use here. So that is not really simpler than your solution.

Comment: Thank you @ArcticChar.

Answer (score 7):

because
\begin{gather*}
1\leq \sqrt[n]{1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2}\leq \sqrt[n]{n\cdot n^2}
=(\sqrt[n]{n})^3,\end{gather*}
and
\begin{gather*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n]{n})^3=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^3=1,
\end{gather*}
we have, by the squeeze test,
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2}=1.$

Comment: Nice, but not new: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/611803/42969.

Answer (score 2):

A computation without $\epsilon$ but assuming a closed formula for the sum of the first $n$ squares.

For $n\ge 1$,
$a_n=\sqrt[n]{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)\right) \to \exp(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^a \sim  \frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1}$
because $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k/n)^a =\int_{0}^{1} x^a dx=\frac{1}{a+1}$$

So $$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left [\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 \right]^{1/n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} (n^3/3)^{1/n}= \lim_{n\to \infty} \exp[\frac{1}{n} \ln (n^3/3)]=\lim_{n \to \infty} \exp[\frac{1}{n}(3 \ln n-\ln3)]=e^{0}=1. $$

Comment: We have a simple formula for $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^n {k^2 }$, no need to make the argument unnecessarily complicated using asymptotics.